# PgAdmin 4: Cannot edit rows from one table

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Something strange is happening with my new created tables in Postgres, I can add data to them, but I cannot use PgAdmin to edit the any row.

This is my table columns description:

[image: Table columns]

After executing the query to view all table rows this is what I can see:

[image: Right click at the table]

[image: At the Data Output]

Save button is disabled to update my table rows. But this is happening only with my new created tables, as you can see, I have other tables where I'm able to edit rows, for example at this table of Users:

[image: Other table that is able to edit data]

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Found the problem! That was happening, because I didn't select any of the columns as 'Primary key':

[image: Table columns description updated]

Comment: Oracle Database rowid values contain information necessary to locate a row. Exists some of similar in postgres for edit row with "dynamic primary key"?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was doing a join and pgAdmin didn't like that. I had to query the table directly.